# textView setText() and append() crashing when OnClick function is called

Tags: java, android-intent, textview, sudoku, settext

I'm making a Sudoku app and I want to add a Move Counter so I have a textView that is displayed with the movecount every time the user inputs a number

```
public class NumberButton extends Button implements OnClickListener {

    private int number;
    TextView moveCountText;
    private int moves;
    private String message;

    public NumberButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOnClickListener(this);
        moveCountText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.moveCountView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        moves++;
        message="Move Count: "+ moves;
        moveCountText.setText(message);
        moveCountText.invalidate();


        GameEngine.getInstance().setNumber(number);
    }

    public void setNumber(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Trouble is, the setText says the view is empty(null object) but I don't know why. Here is the textView XML.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Move count: 0"
    android:id="@+id/moveCountView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="114dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="450dp"/>
```

The same is happening for my victory activity, the error is that the intent is a null object

```
public void checkGame(){
    int [][] sudGrid = new int[9][9];
    for( int x = 0 ; x < 8 ; x++ ){
        for( int y = 0 ; y < 8 ; y++ ){
            sudGrid[x][y] = getItem(x,y).getValue();
        }
    }

    if( SudokuChecker.getInstance().checkSudoku(sudGrid)){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Congratulations!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // opens victory screen
        Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VictoryActivity.class);
        startActivity(nextScreen);
    }
}
```

Here is the error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at sudoku.view.buttonsgrid.NumberButton.onClick(NumberButton.java:33)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

And the XML

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Move count: 0"
    android:id="@+id/moveCountView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="114dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="450dp"/>
```

Comment: What's the exceptions message?

Comment: When you ask question please post you stack trace too.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 added the error message

Comment: @MehrajMalik Sorry, first time asking on this site.

Answer (score 0):

you moveCountText is  null every time you are setting text to it.

**Change this-**

```
setOnClickListener(this); 
moveCountText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.moveCountView);
```

**to-**

```
moveCountText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.moveCountView);
moveCountText.setOnClickListner(this);
```

and implement View.OnClickListner
will work for you :)

Comment: Thanks that worked but it's now saying that the
moveCountText.setText(message);
is referring to a null object :(

Comment: please verify that you are inflating correct xml in setContextView(R.layour.YOUR_XML_FILE_NAME);

Comment: added the xml for that view